# Identify a quadric

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, affine-geometry

Could you tell me how to identify a given quadric?
Given a conic section, I should find an orthonormal affine frame in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with standard dot product) in which the equation has a canonical form.

Could you solve for example $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 73x^2 + 72xy + 52y^2 - 220x - 40y - 2300=0\}$ ? Or $x^2 - 6xy + 9y^2 + 2x - 5y -1=0$ ?

Thank you.

I would really appreciate a thorough explanation, because Kostrikin gives only the answers - there are no full solutions there.

For the second exmple I thought I could begin with a basis $(0,1), (1,0)$

$(x-3y)^2 + 2x-5y-1=0$ We set $\alpha = x-3y, \ \ \beta=y$, so $x=\alpha + 3\beta$.

$(0,0) + (x(1,0) + y(0,1)) = (0,0) + ((\alpha + 3\beta)(1,0) + \beta(0,1)) = (0,0) + \alpha(1,0) + \beta(3,1)$

So we have $\alpha^2 + 2 \alpha +  \beta -1 = 0$

$(\alpha + 1)^2 + \beta -2 = 0$

Then we set $\alpha_1 = \alpha + 1$, $\beta_1 = \beta -1$

The problem is that I don't know how to make the basis stay orthonormal.

Comment: "Quadric" means degree four :P Anyway, this problem has a relatively easy solution, but the only explanation I know for why it is valid requires some projective geometry. Have you seen any?

Comment: @eric: According to convention, the term "Quadric" refers to degree two in this case (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric). "quadratic" is not correct.

Comment: Hm :/ I've never seen that convention but I generally trust Wikipedia. I changed it back.

Comment: hmm, maybe has developed from a shorting of "quadratic form" or something. Also, should degree four not be called "quartic"?

Comment: @EricStucky: Could you show me that solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses projective geometry, in particular the fact that there is a unique conic up to isometry in the real projective plane, and that when embedding this into $\overline{\mathbb{R}^2}$, the type of conic it corresponds to in the restriction to $\mathbb{R}$ is characterized by how many ideal points it contains. We use the homogeneous coordinates in $\overline{\mathbb{R}^2}$ such that ideal points have $x_3=0$.

> Let $q(x)=0$ be the homogenous equation of a projective conic in $\overline{\mathbb{R}^2}$ where $q$ is a quadratic form with $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix $M=(a_{ij})$. Show that whether the conic is an ellipse, a parabola, or a hyperbola in the restriction to $\mathbb{R}$ is determined by the sign of the upper-left $2\times 2$ minor of $M$.

Consider the ideal points of this conic: such points have $x_3=0$, and without loss of generality we may consider the representative vectors on the hyperplane $x_2=1$. Then
$$ q(x^*) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13} \\ a_{12}&a_{22}&a_{23} \\ a_{13}&a_{23}&a_{33} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = a_{11}x_1^2+2a_{12}x_1+a_{22}.$$
The number of solutions to this quadratic is found by considering the sign of the discriminant $(2a_{12})^2-4a_{11}a_{22}$. Notice that this is precisely $-4$ times the upper-left $2\times 2$ minor of $M$.

Explicitly: if the discriminant is positive, then there are two solutions to $q(x^*)=0$; if the discriminant is negative, there are none, and if it is zero, there is one. Since these solutions are the ideal points in the conic, this can be rewritten in the desired form: The conic is an ellipse precisely when the minor is positive, a parabola precisely when the minor is zero, and a hyperbola precisely when the minor is negative.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also take a look at my partial "solution". My biggest worry is the orthonormal basis.

Comment: Having not done anything similar before, I'm not sure what basis you are talking about, nor what it is doing.

Comment: I need to find an orthonormal affine frame $(a, v_1, v_2)$ where $a$ is a point and $v_1, v_2$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the quadric has a form as in here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric for example $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}+ \frac{z^2}{c^2} =1$

Answer (score 1):

Given the equation $ x^2 -6xy +9y^2 +2x -5y -1 = 0 \tag{1} $

Let's consider the linear transformation $ T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ associated to $
A =[T]_\mathscr{C_2} = \begin{pmatrix}1&-3\\-3&9\\ \end{pmatrix}
$ where $\mathscr{C_2}$ is the canonical base of $\mathbb{R^2}$, and the vector $L=(2,-5) $

If $v=(x,y)$ is an arbitrary vector of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we know that
$$ [T(v)]_\mathscr{C_2} = A \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&-3\\-3&9\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x-3y \\ -3x+9y \end{pmatrix} $$

Then, $$ \langle T(v) , v \rangle = \langle (x-3y,-3x+9y),(x,y) \rangle = x^2 -6xy +9^2 $$
And therefore, the equation (1) can be re-written as
$$ \langle T(v) , v \rangle + \langle L , v \rangle -1 = 0 \tag{2} $$

Since $T$ is a symmetric lineaer transformation, there exist some orthonormal basis $B$ formed by eigenvectors such that $[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0&\lambda_2 \end{pmatrix}$, where $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues. Also, since $B$ and $\mathscr{C_2}$ are orthonormal basis, we have that
$$ \forall v \in \mathbb{R^2}: \langle T(v), v \rangle = \langle (T(v))_B, (v)_B \rangle \tag {3}$$

Let's seek $B$. Firs, we calculate the eigenvalues:

$$ p(\lambda) = |A-\lambda I | = \begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda&-3 \\-3& 9-\lambda \end{vmatrix}= \lambda^2-10\lambda=\lambda (\lambda-10) \implies \lambda_1=10 ;\lambda_2=0$$

If $\lambda=\lambda_1=10$, we can calculate the associated eigenvectors
$$\begin{pmatrix}1-10&-3\\-3&9-10 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0 \end{pmatrix} \implies y=-3x$$
so $ V_{10} = \{(x,-3x):x\in\mathbb{R} \} = span{\{ (1,-3)\}}$ and we take a vector of norm 1 in $V_{10}$.
$$\vec b_1 = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}) $$

Applying the same procedure for $\lambda=\lambda_2=0$, we get:
$$V_0 = span\{(3,1)\} \implies \vec b_2 = (\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}})$$

Therefore, $$B=\{ (\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}),(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}) \}  \implies [B]_\mathscr{C_2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \begin{pmatrix} 1&3\\-3&1\end{pmatrix} $$

Also, we need the vector $L$ expressed in the basis $B$.
$$ [L]_B = [\mathscr{C_2}]_B [L]_\mathscr{C_2} = [B]_\mathscr{C_2}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2\\-5\end{pmatrix} = [B]_\mathscr{C_2}^{T} \begin{pmatrix} 2\\-5\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \begin{pmatrix} 1&-3\\3&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2\\-5\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \begin{pmatrix} 17\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, for (2), (3) and the previous data we can express the original equation in a new system $(O,X'Y')$ associated with the basis $B$.

$$ 10x'^2 + \frac{17}{\sqrt{10}}x'+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}y' -1 = 0$$
$$ 10\left( x'+ \frac{17}{20\sqrt{10}}\right) ^2 = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \left( y' -\frac{689\sqrt{10}}{400} \right)$$

We make a translation to a new origin of coordinates $O'$. Let $\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x''= x'+ \frac{17}{20\sqrt{10}} \\ 
y'' = y' -\frac{689\sqrt{10}}{400}
\end{array}
\right.$

Then
$$x''^2=-\frac{1}{10\sqrt{10}} y''$$

Which is clearly a parabola.

Comment: Maybe I committed a calculation error, but the procedure is the one you requested and you can use it as a model for the other excercise.

Comment: The linear transformation and the vector $L$ are choosen with this method: In general, the equation has the form $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$, so the matrix has to be $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\b&c \end{pmatrix} $ and $L=(d,e)$.